# Sails lift successful but I get 404 error on navigating to localhost:1337

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Sails lift shows server running on port 1337. I go to the url localhost:1337 it shows 404 page. What might be the problem here.

Its my local dev machine running ubuntu 16.04 and also has apache2 installed

- sails v0.10.5,
- node v4.2.6

verbose option on sails lift does not give any information apart from showing the environment and port details

My Blueprint.js file

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
    actions: true,
    rest: true,
    shortcuts: true,
    prefix: '',
    pluralize: false,
    populate: true,
    autoWatch: true,
};
```

My route.js file

```
module.exports.routes = {
    '/': {
        view: 'homepage'
     },
}
```

After adding routes, I get the following output and not a 404 error

```
{
    "path": "/var/www/Projects/my-project/sails-app/views/homepage.ejs"
}
```

as there is an error which is something related to i18 module `Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined path`.

Comment: please show the `config/routes.js`.

Comment: ok there is nothing under module.exports.route.

Comment: how did you created the sails app, did you followed [all these steps](http://sailsjs.com/get-started)? and refer [this for creating routes](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes)

Comment: Yeah Raghav, this is an old repo created by few of my colleagues and I am new here. The repo is working on production environment on aws. I want to make a local copy of it on my machine for debugging. I did add now  'get /': { view: 'views/homepage.ejs' }, for my module exports but still no luck.

Comment: Please add your whole code for, `routes.js`, `blueprint.js`, in your question

Comment: can you please add the full error, or is it just what you added in the question.? and do you have a file `views/homepage.ejs`?